# how to make setTimeOut to run the counter animation more faster?

Tags: javascript, animation

I have this piece of code for a counter. I want to run it very fast like the speed of light because the numbers are in thousands and right now the animation looks very silly and so slow, please any idea? or maybe a better approach?

```
const stat = document.querySelectorAll(".stats span");

export const startCounter = () => {
    stat.forEach(stat => {
        console.log("fore");
        
        let counter = 0;

        function updateCount() {            
            const traget = parseInt(stat.dataset.count);

            if(counter < traget) {
                console.log("target >");
                
                counter++;
                stat.innerText = counter;
                setTimeout(updateCount, 1);
            }
            
        else {
            console.log("> targ");
            
            stat.innerText = counter.toLocaleString();
        }
        }

        updateCount();

    });
}


startCounter();
```

Comment: You need to update your counter before the element loads on the DOM so you need to write the code accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there's no reason to update the DOM any faster that how quick `requestAnimationFrame` fires, you can use `requestAnimationFrame`s millisecond argument to determine the count - something like the following

This will update the count at exactly 1000 per second - you can make adjustments as you like in the line `const counter = (ms - firstCount) | 0;`

so, you could do `const counter = ((ms - firstCount) * 2) | 0;` to make it twice as fast or `const counter = ((ms - firstCount) / 2) | 0;` for half as fast ... etc

*You could even make adjustments on counter per "stat" - so have them run at different speeds - which I've shown with `data-speed` - defaults to 100(%)*

```js
const stats = document.querySelectorAll(".stats span");

const startCounter = () => {
  let firstCount = 0;
  function updateCount(ms) {
    let cont = false;
    stats.forEach(stat => {
      let target = parseInt(stat.dataset.count);
      const speed = stat.dataset.speed??100;
      const counter = ((ms - firstCount) * speed / 100) | 0;
      if (counter < target) {
        target = counter;
        cont = true;
      }
      stat.innerText = target;
    });
    if (cont) {
      return requestAnimationFrame(updateCount);
    }
    console.log('done');
  }
  requestAnimationFrame((ms) => {
    firstCount = ms;
    requestAnimationFrame(updateCount);
  });
};
startCounter();
```

```html
<div class="stats"><span data-count=1969></span></div>
<div class="stats"><span data-count=3232></span></div>
<div class="stats"><span data-count=2876 data-speed=150></span></div>
<div class="stats"><span data-count=1018 data-speed=90></span></div>
```